# R Global Options Git/SVN Location Problem

Tags: r, git, rstudio

As the previous version of this question was profoundly vague due to my lack of knowledge of Git, let me revise it so that I can be more clear about the problem I am encountering.

Today, I opened a new GitHub repository by cloning its link from Github to R Studio version control so that I could paste the new repository’s link to Git and therefore start to make a new website. However, when I tried this, I received this error, which opened a new page. It was saying that
"Git was not detected on the system path. To create projects from Git repositories, you should install Git and then restart R Studio. Note that if Git is installed and not on the path, then you can specify its location using the Preferences dialog".

As Git was installed on my PC, I am using MacOS, I thought the problem was with the path. To solve it, I tried to change the Git's location from the `R Studio -> Preferences -> Git/SVN panel`. While I am not sure what its initial location was, I changed it to `~/Desktop/GitHub Desktop.app`. After I did this, and as the problem was not solved, I searched the web and saw that the location should be something like `usr/bin/git`. I tried to reformat the location as `usr/bin/git` but I could not since I could not find usr file in the location. When I later posted the question in this forum, one of the users kindly asked me to check the version of my Git. To this end, I wrote the `git --version` in the mac's terminal and I received this error:

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

I searched this error on the web and I looked at several solutions.

One of them was advising to run `xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` but when I did this, I received this error

> xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'

By editing this post, I tried to be specific as much as I could, but as previously stated, since I do not know Git very much, the question might still be vague.

Comment: What's the version of your installed git client?

Comment: how can I learn this?

Comment: This is a great article about this
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/installing-and-upgrading-git-776640906.html

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. Now I checked the it to learn how I can do this. When I wrote `git --version` in the mac's terminal, I receive this error  `xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrune`

Comment: Okey, I was able to solve the problem by mainly following the instructions at these webpages; https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a and https://happygitwithr.com/rstudio-see-git.html . To simplify the workflow for the similar inquiries, what I did was first to run the following code in the MacOS terminal; `xcode-select --install` and then follow the guideline in the second website to find the path of Git for R Studio. Also, thank you @zerocukor287 for the initial help which really helped me.

Comment: Yes, Apple have added this annoying extra step (`xcode-select --install`) before Git works. This was not required in some older macOS versions.